# Does ferrocenium chloride ([Fe(C5H5)2]Cl) exist as a stable compound?

Tags: redox, transition-metals, halides, organometallic-compounds

I am interested in using ferrocenium chloride ($\ce{[Fe(C5H5)2]Cl}$) for a synthesis application, but I couldn't find any sources referring to its existence, even though some websites and a figure in the ferrocene [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrocene) (Figure 6) indicate that it can be produced by reaction with FeCl3.

So my question is, is ferrocenium chloride an existing, stable compound at all? And if it is, does anyone know where more information about it can be found?

Comment: In practice, [tetrafluoroborate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrocenium_tetrafluoroborate) is used. Likely a weakly coordinating ligand is needed if you want to have ferrocenium as a separate ion.

Comment: Figure 6 does not in fact specify ferrocenium chloride as thevproduct with FeCl3. It shows the cation, which could form with a complex counterion.

Answer (score 5):

Ferrocenium appears to be best known with relatively low-nucleophic ions, as opposed to monatomic halides. As Mithoron comments, the most commonly available ferrocenium salt is not any chloride but the tetrafluoroborate.

Toma and Šebesta[1] report:

> Soon after the discovery of ferrocene, its easy oxidation to ferrocenium cation by ferric chloride or benzoquinone was described [2]. Thus, the first isolated ferrocenium salt was ferrocenium tetrachloroferrate. The ferrocenium ion can be prepared with various counterions, such as tetrafluoroborate, hexafluorophosphate, hexafluoroantimonate and tetraphenylborate.

Thus ferrocene oxidized by ferric chloride gives $\ce{Fc^+FeCl4^-}$,not the simple chloride, as the isolated salt, and other counterions are also polyatomic having low nucleophilicty. The best known pure halide of ferrocenium is the iodide, which is actually the triiodide [[3](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567740868004784)] as the iodide ion formed by ferrocene reducing elemental iodine complexes with additional iodine.

**References**

1. Š. Toma and R. Šebesta (2015). "Applicatiins of Ferrocrnium Salts in Organic Synthesis". *Synthesis*, Vol. 47, 1683-1695.
2. G. Wilkinson, M. Rosenblum, M. C. Whiting, R. B. Woodward (1952). _J. Am. Chrm. Soc., Vol. 74, 2125.
3. Tsur Bernstein and F. Herbstein (1968). "The crystal structure of ferricinium triiodide, (C5H5)2FeI3". *Acta Crystallographica Section B Structural Crystallography and Crystal Chemistry*. 24. 1640-1645. 10.1107/S0567740868004784.

Answer (score 1):

Ferrocenium chloride certainly exist and it has been observed during *σ-π* rearrangement of *σ*-complex intermediate. Iron(III) chloride reacts with sodium cyclopentadienide ($\ce{NaCp}$) in the presence of THF at -80 °C to form di/tri-*σ*-cyclopentadienyliron complex which are unstable and rearrange to ferrocenium  chloride and ferrocene at -50 °C.

[image]

(Sic; the source misprinted charge on the chloride ion.)

[image]

It further notes:

> We can anticipate that a ligand-associate (above -60 °C) Fe(III) complex represents a d<sup>5</sup> distorted octahedral, d<sup>2</sup>sp<sup>3</sup>, configuration that is labile and of moderate stability. Thus a *σ-π* rearrangement giving an extremely stable ferrocene. Fe(II), d<sup>6</sup> undistorted octahedral d<sup>2</sup>sp<sup>3</sup> configuration is easily visualized. Similarly, a stable Fe(III) d<sup>5</sup> ferricenium chloride also may be anticipated.

**Reference**:

1. *Introduction to Metal π-Complex Chemistry*, M. Tsutsui, Springer Science & Business Media, **2013**

---

Also note that the reaction between ferrocene with iron(III) chloride does not give ferrocenium chloride, [rather it is a µ-oxo compound $\ce{[Fe^{III}(η-C5H5)2]2[(Fe^{III}Cl3)2O])}$ which is named ferrocenium µ-Oxo-bis[trichloroferrate(III)]](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1986/dt/dt9860001937)

Comment: Too bad the authors rendered chloride ion with two negative charges in the feoorcenium chloride on the upper right. I make a note of this in the answer.

Comment: I find this reaction scheme suspicious. "d2sp3 configuration" doesn't do much good too.

Comment: It maybe, of course, that the chloride ion goes on to complex with additional ferric chloride so that all ferrocenium chloride, like all glory, is fleeting.